# How can I make a NSTextfield with left or right indicator for validation?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I need to make a custom NSTextField with an indicator like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAhfA.png

On the right side, you could see an indicator icon.

What code I need to make this?

Thanks for all.

**EDIT**

The text never could be overlap the icon. The icon is not always displayed, but it can be shown when it is being written and when the text is correct, this text must also occupy the position of the icon.

Comment: Give the text field a subview? See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918473/nsbutton-subview-within-an-nstextfield-why-is-my-button-not-appearing

Comment: @matt, that's true, but the text overlaps the icon. The icon is not always displayed, but it can be shown when it is being written and when the text is correct, this text must also occupy the position of the icon. Now is it clearer?

Comment: So your question is actually how to determine the rect within which the text should be drawn? Then ask that, instead of something so broad.

Comment: @mate I think that with the photo, the question is very clear.

Comment: The photo is clear. What isn’t clear is what _you_ don’t know in order to accomplish your goal. “What code I need to make this?” is too broad. Show your code and explain what part you’re having trouble with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A text field control is a view where the drawing is all done with an NSTextFieldCell. What you'd need to do is subclass NSTextFieldCell, and customize the drawing. Look at `NSCell`'s API and you'll see there's a `drawWithFrame:inView:` method which is what does all of the drawing for the entire field. Various other methods of NSCell are used in this process.

Unfortunately some of how the drawing is done is a bit private and not eeeasily fiddled with, but the main thing is `drawWithFrame:inView:` will draw the background and then call `drawInteriorWithFrame:inView:` to draw the text. Off the top of my head, I can't remember if NSTextFieldCell uses `titleRectForBounds:` to determine what the text's bounds are, but I'm pretty sure it is. So you could override that to return a narrower rectangle, leaving room to either draw the validation icon with the cell itself, or use a subview.

Additionally, you'll need to adjust the bounds in which the NSTextView field editor draws and edits the text, otherwise when you view the field while it is not first responder it will look fine, but when you edit the field's text it will overlap the icon. For that you may need to adjust the frame given to `editWithFrame:inView:editor:delegate:event:`.

It's always a bit finicky to tweak text fields because it takes a while to find all the methods and code paths involved, but that's the gist of what you need to do.